# Random number generation requires too many iterations

Tags: random, iteration, generator, bounds, anylogic

I am running simulations in Anylogic and I'm trying to calibrate the following distribution:

```
Jump = normal(coef1, coef2, -1, 1);
```

However, I keep getting the following message as soon as I start the calibration (experimentation):

> Random number generation requires too many iterations (> 10000)

I tried to replace -1 and 1 by other values and keep getting the same thing.
I also tried to change the bounds of `coef1` and `coef2` and put things like `[0,1]`, but I still get the same error.

I don't get it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AnyLogic's documentation](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/functions/normal.html), there is no version of `normal` which takes 4 arguments.  Also note that if you specify a mean and standard deviation, the order is unusual (to probabilists/statisticians) by putting the standard deviation *before* the mean.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the mean / std. Actually the program compiles and runs well with normal with 4 arguments. Anylogic changed their version but did not update the documentation, or this function is deprecated but still available. If I put fixed values for coef1 and coef2, the program runs fine.

Comment: So an important aspect of your question would be how you're specifying coef1 and coef2.  Nobody can help you find out why something's going wrong if you don't give the full context in which failures occur.

Comment: I found an alternative. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Please stop being aggressive to people trying to answer your question. I think the comments from pjs are perfectly valid: you didn't give enough context for your question.

Comment: @Lou monsieurRigsby's answer is the better one.  Please transfer credit to him for the solution, and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

The four parameter normal method is not deprecated and is not a "calibration where coef1 and coef2 are the coefficicents to be solved for". Where did you get that understanding from? Or are you saying that you're using your AnyLogic Experiment (possibly a multi-run or optimisation experiment) to 'calibrate' that distribution, in which case you need to explain what you mean by 'calibrate' here---what is your desired outcome?

If you look in the API reference (AnyLogic classes and functions --> API Reference --> com.xj.anylogic.engine --> Utilities), you'll see that it's a method to use a truncated normal distribution.

```
public double normal(double min,
                     double max,
                     double shift,
                     double stretch)
```

The first 2 parameters are the min and max (where it will sample repeatedly and ignore values outside the [min,max] range); the second two are effectively the mean and standard deviation. So you will get the error you mentioned if min or max means it will sample too many times to get a value in range.

API reference details below:

> Generates a sample of truncated Normal distribution. Distribution
>   normal(1, 0) is stretched by stretch coefficient, then shifted to the
>   right by shift, after that it is truncated to fit in [min, max]
>   interval. Truncation is performed by discarding every sample outside
>   this interval and taking subsequent try. For more details see
>   normal(double, double)
>
> Parameters:
>       min - the minimum value that this function will return. The distribution is truncated to return values above this. If the sample
>   (stretched and shifted) is below this value it will be discarded and
>   another sample will be drawn. Use -infinity for "No limit".
>       max - the maximum value that this function will return. The distribution is truncated to return values below this. If the sample
>   (stretched and shifted) is bigger than this value it will be discarded
>   and another sample will be drawn. Use +infinity for "No limit".
>       shift - the shift parameter that indicates how much the (stretched) distribution will shifted to the right = mean value
>       stretch - the stretch parameter that indicates how much the distribution will be stretched = standard deviation Returns:
>       the generated sample

Comment: Seriously ?? <<Where did you get that understanding from ?>> ??? And you, where did you get the understanding that <<The four parameter normal method is a "calibration where coef1 and coef2 are the coefficicents to be solved for".>> ????
If you do not understand the question, just don't reply ! Don't say to people they are agressive when you are aggressive as well. 
If you do not understand something, you formulate a question. But don't play this chidish game of "where did you get this understanding from ???" Like you're smarter than everyone !

Comment: This question is closed. I have no interest wasting anymore time with both of you. Your answers are not bringing any value. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Lou Um, deleting your comment to pjs where you were aggressive, and where you said that your model was a "calibration where coef1 and coef2 are the coefficicents to be solved for", is not cool. I just meant 'how did you arrive at that understanding?' since you were saying that you had to 'calibrate the distribution' and that 'AnyLogic did not update their documentation'. So it seemed that you had read something that led you to understand that it was a distribution that you needed to calibrate, or were trying to calibrate for some wider reason (hence the sentence afterwards).

Comment: Given the wider context of my answer as a whole (especially the 3rd sentence), I think you've jumped to a conclusion about the tone of the 'understanding' bit. I'm sorry if you were offended by it, but your reaction was not the best.

Comment: I did not delete any comment.